# Cannot read property 'findDOMNode' of undefined when using stopPropagation - reactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-bubbling, react-dom

I need to do event bubbling through the deep nested components ,  I tried to do some thing like below

```
   import {ReactDOM,render, unmountComponentAtNode} from 'react-dom';

  .........
  .........

  componentDidMount() {
    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
  }, false)
}
```

I got the following error

```
bundle.js:45 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'findDOMNode' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

`ReactDOM` is default export, import `findDOMNode` instead of `ReactDOM`.
Try this:

```
import {findDOMNode ,render, unmountComponentAtNode} from 'react-dom';
...
componentDidMount() {
    findDOMNode(this).addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
  }, false)
}
```

OR

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
...
componentDidMount() {
    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
  }, false)
}
```